# How to fill the entire region of any image after or before performing canny edge?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0

[Sample Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6g6c.png)

[Sample partial output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc1Kq.jpg)

I want to fill all the white regions inside the card.

Comment: Your question shows no effort and is quite unclear. I would suggest you improve it before it gets downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: Why do you need that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hole filling functiong, but because of the finger, the QR won't get filled.

Given the simple geometry of the card, I would advise to find the sides and just reconstruct a rounded rectangle.